# apscheduler: how to prevent console printing of job misfire warning message?

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

How to prevent apscheduler from printing job misfire (error) warning to the console ?

As you can see in console output, the job misfire event is captured and handled on a proper way.
But the red message from apscheduler scare normal users, they think the program is crashed, while nothing is wrong at all.

Why print this to the console, if an event scheduler is defined ? After defining an scheduler (EVENT_JOB_MISSED) event listener, the programmer is responsible for the console output.

Apscheduler is a great module, but this issue is a little minor.

```py
def SetScheduler():
    global shedul
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    from apscheduler.events import  EVENT_JOB_ERROR, EVENT_JOB_MISSED
    shedul = BackgroundScheduler()
    shedul.add_listener(shed_listener, EVENT_JOB_MISSED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
```

Console output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust your logging configuration to filter out these messages.
If you don't need to display any apscheduler logging, you could do:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("apscheduler").propagate = False
```

If you want to display other messages but not these specific ones, you may need to add a filter to that logger, but I have no experience on that. You can check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/logging.html#filter-objects) on that yourself.